# How to debounce on showing loading overlay template

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using ag-grid and ag-grid-angular v9.0.0. I need to show loading overlay template after 2 seconds if the rows are empty otherwise hide it. Currently it shows instantly and goes away after rows are rendered. Any clues or suggestions on how to accomplish is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settimeout function pass 2000 as argument

```
setTimeout(() => {
    //Execute code here 
    }, 2000);
```